# Component One Pdfviewer override save button

Tags: silverlight, componentone, pdfviewer

Is there any way to override the save button on a PDFViewer from Component One?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [sample](http://our.componentone.com/samples/silverlight-customtoolbar) which shows how to create a custom C1ReportViewer or C1PDFViewer toolbar. The same can be implemented with the C1.WPF.Toolbar as well.

Regards,
mohita